# Load visual editor without custom styling

Tags: plugin-development, wp-editor, add-editor-style

I have a plugin that uses the `wp_editor()` function to load an instance of the TinyMCE editor.

However, the editor is affected by custom styling to make it look similar to the theme through the `add_editor_style()` function. While this may be great in giving the user an idea of how the content may look on the front-end, I do not want this as the content will only ever be displayed on the back-end.

Is there any way to load an instance of the WordPress editor without it being affected by custom styling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While @s_ha_dum’s solution works fine on a custom plugin page, it will fail if you use TinyMCE on a post editor page after the first editor instance has been called, because it would either affect all editors or at least the editors later on the same page. TinyMCE parses custom styles into its settings during the first run only.

How to remove the custom styles for **one editor only**?

Let’s say we replace the excerpt box with a rich editor in a class with static methods only:

```
wp_editor(
    self::unescape( $post->post_excerpt ),
    'excerpt', // $editor_id
    array (
    'textarea_rows' => 15
,   'media_buttons' => FALSE
,   'teeny'         => TRUE
,   'tinymce'       => TRUE
,   'first_init' => TRUE
    )
);
```

To remove the custom styles for just one special editor ID, we can filter `teeny_mce_before_init` if we have set `'teeny' => TRUE` and `tiny_mce_before_init` otherwise.

See `_WP_Editors::editor_settings()`:

```
// For people who really REALLY know what they're doing with TinyMCE
// You can modify $mceInit to add, remove, change elements of the config before tinyMCE.init
// Setting "valid_elements", "invalid_elements" and "extended_valid_elements" can be done through this filter.
// Best is to use the default cleanup by not specifying valid_elements, as TinyMCE contains full set of XHTML 1.0.
if ( $set['teeny'] ) {
    $mceInit = apply_filters('teeny_mce_before_init', $mceInit, $editor_id);
} else {
    $mceInit = apply_filters('tiny_mce_before_init', $mceInit, $editor_id);
}
```

In this example it is `teeny_mce_before_init`, and we need a simple helper method:

```
public static function no_custom_css( $settings, $editor_id )
{
    'excerpt' === $editor_id and $settings['content_css'] = '';
    return $settings;
}
```

Now we register that as callback before we call `wp_editor()`:

```
add_filter( 'teeny_mce_before_init', array ( __CLASS__, 'no_custom_css' ), 10, 2 );
```

That’s all. Only editors with our ID will get no custom styles now. No untestable side effect, our code stays compatible with other code in all situations.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want [`remove_editor_styles`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_editor_styles). Looks like it [removes the theme support](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5//wp-includes/theme.php#L1232) for editor styles.

```
remove_editor_styles();
```

If you run that on your plugin's backend page before the editor boots, it should solve the problem. There might be a parameter you can pass to the editor functions, or a hook, but removing the editor style support for the effected page was the first thing that came to my mind.

Untested and I haven't done much with editor styles but it seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks - just tested in in my plugin and it works like a charm! I wonder why I didn't think of it myself, as I have heard of this function before